# peace lilly is rotting from the heat (possible?)?

Tags: houseplants, watering, roots, peace-lily

I have a long-loved peace Lilly that has recently taken a turn for the worst. Some time ago, SE advised me that the pot it was in did not have appropriate drainage, and saved this very plant. It was very healthy from there on out, until this past couple of weeks.

I came home from a trip, and the plant was a little dry (According to the reader I use). I gave it a good watering, and it half perked, then sort of stopped. Then drooped. Then got brown and rotted. I've had to cut away the vast majority of it - hoping it can survive though!

[image: eThe last healthy remainder of the plant][image: A view that shows the rot source - most fo the leaves were pulled easily from this area.][image: The dead or mostly dead leaves I removed.]

Our water is hard, I sometimes use bottled water to balance this out. I wonder if not enough - judging by the crust on the pot. I also wonder abotu temperature; it was recently in the mid 40's degrees c (107-115F). Is that too much for this plant?

It is in indirect light, of roughly the brightness you see in the photo. It gets maybe 1 hour of direct light (through window) per day.  I'm concerend that if I pull it up to check the roots, it'll be game over.

Should I water this plant? The soil is still quite moist to the touch. What other diagnostics could I do?

Comment: Update: This plant died. It continued to suffer, I pruned back the most dead leaves. I left the roots in place with the hope that it'd send something up, but no luck thus far.